# Error : Variations does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I´ve got a problem with an error message

```
Variations does not name a type.
```

I´m doing exactly the same thing with Variations as I do with GGG. Nevertheless I get an error `Variations does not name a type` (When I type th code for Variations the editor seems to know Variations ).
Does anybody have an idea why I get this error?

Thank you

Sabine

```
    #ifndef VARPMAXPARA_H
    #define VARPMAXPARA_H

    #include "Tab.h"
    #include "GuiUtils/ItemModelVariations.h"
    #include "PrManager.h"
    #include "Variations.h"
    #include "GGG.h"

    #include <QButtonGroup>
    namespace Ui {
    class VarPmaxPara;
    }

    class VarPmaxPara : public Tab
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit VarPmaxPara(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~VarPmaxPara();

….


    private:
        Ui::VarPmaxPara *ui;

        QButtonGroup bg_AP;

        // Interaction
        PrManager* PrManager;
        Variations* variations;
        GGG* ggg;
    };

    #endif // VARPMAXPARA_H
```

Comment: Perhaps your `Variations.h` is broken? Or one of the other headers?

Comment: try to use a forward declaration for GGG and Variation if you can. And move the inclusion on cpp file. It avoids a lot of problems and unwanted inclusions...

Comment: Since the name "Variations" is known, it could be a variable or namespace declared somewhere.

Comment: Does your `Variations.h` file by any chance directly or indirectly include your `VarPmaxPara.h`?